# nested query with laravel model

Tags: laravel

I am writing a nested query with Laravel.
Namely First, the Truck information is drawn, then I list the data of the vehicle with "truck_history", there is no problem until here, but I want to show the information of the invoice belonging to the "invoice_id" in truck_history. but I couldn't understand how to query, I want to do it in the model, is this possible? If possible, how will it be done?

"ID" COLUMN IN INVOICE TABLE AND "invoice_id" in "InvoiceDetail" match.

[image]
**TruckController**

```
public function getTruck($id)
    {
        $truck = Truck::with(['truckHistory'])->find($id);
        return $truck;
    }
```

**Truck Model**

```
protected $appends = ['company_name'];

    public function companys()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Contact::class, 'company_id', 'id');
    }

    public function getCompanyNameAttribute()
    {
       return $this->companys()->first()->name;
    }

    public function truckHistory(){
        return $this->hasMany(InvoiceDetail::class,'plate_no','plate');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can add another relationship in the InvoiceDetail::class and add in the truck history.
try something like this:

```
public function truckHistory(){
    return $this->hasMany(InvoiceDetail::class,'plate_no','plate')->with('Invoice');
}
```

Comment: it didn't work this way it gives an error

Comment: did you add the Invoice relationship?

Comment: try this:
        $truck = Truck::with(['truckHistory.Invoice'])->find($id);

Comment: ```message: "Call to undefined relationship [Invoice] on model [App\Models\InvoiceDetail].",…}
exception: "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\RelationNotFoundException"
file: "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\YeniMuhasebe\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\RelationNotFoundException.php"
line: 34
message: "Call to undefined relationship [Invoice] on model [App\\Models\\InvoiceDetail].```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the following relations (if you don't already have them):

Invoice model :

```
public function truckHistory()
{
    return $this->hasOne(InvoiceDetail::class);
}
```

InvoiceDetail model :

```
public function invoice()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Invoice::class);
}
```

And you can get the relation `invoice` of the relation `truckHistory` adding a point as separator :

```
public function getTruck($id)
{
    $truck = Truck::with(['truckHistory.invoice'])->find($id);
    return $truck;
}
```

Comment: I do not have such a relationship

Comment: I don't have a model called Truck History model

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake, I edited